# How to get value from string using preg_match php?

Tags: php

How to get value from string using preg_match php ?

This below code. I tried to get value `08-dec-2021` between `Expiration Date:` and  `>>> Last update of whois`

I tried to tested my code but not work. (not echo anything and show error 
`Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found in on line 3`)

```
<?php
$test_text = "Updated Date: 04-feb-2014 Creation Date: 08-dec-2009 Expiration Date: 08-dec-2021 >>> Last update of whois >>> database: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 03:56:01 GMT";
preg_match('/Expiration Date: "(.+?)" >>> Last update of whois database',$test_text,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
?>
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Did you investigate what your error message meant? Regex must end with the same delimiter you started with; in this case `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change 3 things
**1**. Omit `""` from regex
**2**. You did not put "`/`" at the end of regex
**3**. Change "`Last update of whois database`" to "`Last update of whois >>> database"`
Omit `""` from regex

```
<?php
$test_text = "Updated Date: 04-feb-2014 Creation Date: 08-dec-2009 Expiration Date: 08-dec-2021 >>> Last update of whois >>> database: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 03:56:01 GMT";
preg_match('/Expiration Date: (.+?) >>> Last update of whois >>> database/',$test_text,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Working **[Example](https://eval.in/557262)**

Comment: Please let me know you are done or not @mongmong seesee

Comment: If it works, you should accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from it. Thank you@mongmong-seesee

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as you are doing by preg_match using code below

```
$test_text = "Updated Date: 04-feb-2014 Creation Date: 08-dec-2009 Expiration Date: 08-dec-2021 >>> Last update of whois >>> database: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 03:56:01 GMT";
preg_match('/Expiration Date: (.+?) >>>/',$test_text,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Or you can also do by substr function try below code

```
$test_text = "Updated Date: 04-feb-2014 Creation Date: 08-dec-2009 Expiration Date: 08-dec-2021 >>> Last update of whois >>> database: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 03:56:01 GMT";

$pos=strrpos($test_text,"Expiration Date")+strlen("Expiration Date: ");
echo substr($test_text,$pos,11);
```